# Angular Formly Form hook OnInit -> field.xxx is possibly undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-formly, ngx-formly

Angular version: 16.0
Formly version: 6.1.8

I'd need to create a cascated select for my app. The first field is a Material Autocomplete and then the next one a simple select
I'm struggling, however, using hooks because field.parent appears to be possibly undefined:

```
(property) FormlyFieldConfig<FormlyFieldProps & { [additionalProperties: string]: any; }>.parent?: FormlyFieldConfig<FormlyFieldProps & {
    [additionalProperties: string]: any;
}> | undefined
```

So TypeScript is complaining when I try to access the previous field:

```
'field.parent' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)
```

I'm confused about what I'm doing wrong in my context to have this object that's potentially "undefined".

```
form = new FormGroup({});
  sendForm: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'thirdParty',
      type: 'autocomplete',
      props: {
        createLink: '/third-parties/create-thirdparty',
        required: true,
        label: 'Tercero',
        displayProp: 'displayName',
        valueProp: 'id',
        placeholder: 'Empresa XYZ',
        filter: (term: string) => {
          return this.thirdParties.asObservable().pipe(
            map(thirdParties => term ? this.filterThirdParties(term, thirdParties) : thirdParties)
        )},
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'user',
      type: 'select',
      props: {
        label: 'Usuario',
        options: [],
        required: true,
      },
      hooks: {
        onInit: (field: FormlyFieldConfig) => {
          const thirdParty = field.parent.get('thirdParty'); // <---- Here's the problem. 
        }
      },
      expressions: {
        hide: '!model.thirdParty',
      }
    }
  ];
  model = null;
  options: FormlyFormOptions = {};
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of your issue on https://codesandbox.io/. This will allow the community to better understand the specific challenges you're facing and offer more targeted assistance.

Answer (score 1):

`field.parent` is possibly `undefined`, use a Optional chaining operator (`.?`) to call the method.  `field.parent?.get('thirdParty')`

Comment: I've tried it and for some reason it's still complaining... 
no matter if it's an if statement, the "?" or the a controversial "!" nothing will do. The solution I found, which I hate, is to specify (field: any) instead of (field: FormlyFieldConfig)...